# .htaccess: how to return 404 instead of 301 for directories with missing ending slash

Tags: .htaccess

I want to hide my existing files and directories which are not intended for the visitors by returning a 404 status. So far I have succeeded to cover these scenarios (let's say I have a file "file.txt" and a directory called "dir"):

- *example.net/file.txt* returns 404 ✔
- *example.net/dir/* returns 404 ✔
- *example.net/dir/anyFileIHaveHere.txt* returns 404 ✔

However "*example.net/dir*" **returns 301** status with a location to "*example.net/dir/*". I have read that browsers remember 301 redirects so to be sure that there is no cache disturbing my tests, I am sending the request via curl:
`curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store' -X GET -v 'https://example.net/dir'`

It happens only with the existing directories, so this method can be used to "guess" my directories which I want to prevent. I have tried everything I found online in order to return 404, but none of these worked so far:

- ErrorDocument 301 /pages/404.php
- RewriteRule "/dir" "/pages/404.php"
- DirectorySlash Off
- FilesMatch dir with deny from all
- Location dir with deny from all

Maybe I just did not used or combined them correctly or maybe there is something else. The host is hostinger if this is a sign of anything. What would be the approach I need?

My current .htaccess in root:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /pages/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404.php

<FilesMatch "file1|file2|fileN">
  order Allow, Deny
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

.htaccess in /dir:

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `DirectorySlash Off` (as you suggested) in the root `.htaccess` file to prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash on the filesystem directory via a 301 (permanent) redirect.

However, this alone won't trigger the `/dir/.htaccess` file (that "blocks" the request) since this requires the trailing slash on the directory. You could either manually append the trailing slash with mod_rewrite or simply use mod_rewrite to "block" the request directly (preferable). By "block", I mean serve a 404 - no need to trigger a 403 and override this in your PHP custom error document.

You *might* also need to set `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash` to allow mod_rewrite to match directories that do not end with a trailing slash. (I say "might", because this is not always necessary, despite [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) suggesting it is.)

Note that `DirectorySlash Off` will prevent the trailing slash from being appended to any directory. So, depending on your scenario, you might need to manually append the trailing slash as required if you have other directories that need to be accessible.

Also note (as you pointed out), 301 redirects are cached persistently by the browser. They are intended to be "permanent" after all. (You can control the caching by sending the appropriate `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers.)

So, in the root `.htaccess` you could add the following:

```
# Root ".htaccess"

# Directory listings "must" be disabled when "DirectorySlash Off" is set
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash with a 301 redirect
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Allow mod_rewrite to match directories that do not end with a slash
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# Trigger 404 when directory (or any file in that directory) is requested
# Directory can be requested with or without the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^dir(/|$) - [R=404]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does **not** start with a slash.

The `.htaccess` file in the `/dir` subdirectory is no longer required.

You could use the same method for all files and directories you need to block. No need for the 403 `ErrorDocument` that overrides/sets the "404 Not Found" response. For example, the complete file would be like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404.php

Options -Indexes

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# Trigger 404 for specific files and directories (and all files in those directories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir(/|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/another-dir(/|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file1\.txt$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file2\.txt$
RewriteRule . - [R=404]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-path. Unlike the `RewriteRule` *pattern* which is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file and consequently does *not* start with a slash.

---

> ```
> <FilesMatch "file1|file2|fileN">
> ```

Note that this matches any file (anywhere on the filesystem) that *contains* either `file1`, `file2` or `fileN` anywhere in the filename (not file-path). So, the file `/foo/bar/abcfile1xyz.txt` would be successfully matched by this rule. You can repeat this in a mod_rewrite condition or rule if you wish. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} file1|file2|fileN [OR]
```

---

Additional notes...

> ```
> ErrorDocument 301 /pages/404.php
> ```

This might allow you to override the HTTP response *body* of the redirect response (which is generally ignored by the user-agent), but you can't override the 3xx redirect using this method. The 3xx response consists of a HTTP status and a `Location` header.

> ```
> RewriteRule "/dir" "/pages/404.php"
> ```

As mentioned above, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash. So this would never match. (However, you should trigger the 404 directly, rather than internally rewriting to the 404 error document. Apache then sets the correct status code, without relying on PHP.)

> FilesMatch dir with deny from all

The `FilesMatch` directive matches against physical files only, not directories.

> Location dir with deny from all

The `Location` directive is not permitted in a `.htaccess` context so this should have resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error on Apache. (On LiteSpeed it may just get ignored.)

> ```
> order Allow, Deny
> deny from all
> ```

These are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 (I assume you are on Apache 2.4). You should be using `Require all denied` here instead. But you should not mix auth directives from both modules in the same context as this can result in unexpected conflicts.

Comment: A feel like the upvote and the answer check is not enough to thank you also the detailed explanations. <3 Now everything works as intended.

I really have to spend more time on studying .htaccess.